# Object detection in android using ORB

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection, object-detection, orb

I'm trying to detect certain objects with the camera of an android device. I've tried the OpenCV people detection sample using HOG descriptor but that seems to be pretty slow. Then I tried using Haar Cascades which gave a better average frame rate of 10 fps and better accuracy as well.

After reading a bit more, another viable option seems to be the ORB feature detector. What I could understand is that I need to save the feature vectors of the images against which I want to compare the current frame. So,

- What would be the best way to store these vectors on an android device
- How big a database of images would I need for decent accuracy (suppose I use it for people detection) & what could be the overhead of comparing against a large database
- Also, what limitations does ORB present regarding color differences of objects and distance from camera

Comment: Orb does not take color into consideration, it works on grayscale images.

Comment: @GilLevi Okay. I have another question. Is feature based object detection suitable for a more generalized detection like people or vehicles?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you found a solution to recognize object with ORB?

Comment: @Crash-ID Partially. Got a lot of false positives with ORB.

Comment: Did you have any success with any other method? Can you give an advise what to use to detect object (particularly I need to detect car steering wheel and car wheel, I don't need to recognize the exactly same object but to say whether is a steering wheel, wheel or not). I tried with haar classifier but without success.